# Python 3.x Blank print under Pycharm but results under Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, atom-editor

I had something what I cannot understand and find the reason , I got few lines of code which returns the request response in Atom editor under Linux but also returns blank response when run in Pycharm or on Windows Server 2016 cmd

```
import requests


def get_page(url):

    response = requests.get(url)

    print(response.ok)


def main():
    url = 'https://www.google.com'
    get_page(url)
```

What may be the reason for that ?

Comment: do both atom and pycharm use the same python path?

Comment: Atom is under Linux MInt - pycharm under Wsever2016
And I dont really care about Atom and Linux as I need this to work under Windows- I cannot understand what is happening